# Odoo 11 Setup Company Error

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I seted up Odoo 11 and something wrong when I click to Setup the Company information on Configuration>Accounting.

I don't know how fix it. Someone can help me on this error?

```
Erro: Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 937, in __get__
        value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 960, in get
        value = self._data[field][record.id][key] KeyError: <odoo.api.Environment object at 0x7ff733c1d048>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib64/python3.5/base64.py", line 519, in
_input_type_check
    m = memoryview(s) TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/br_base/models/res_company.py", line 87, in
_compute_expiry_date
    self.with_context(bin_size=False).nfe_a1_file)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib64/python3.5/base64.py", line 561, in decodestring
    return decodebytes(s)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib64/python3.5/base64.py", line 553, in decodebytes
    _input_type_check(s)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11-venv/lib64/python3.5/base64.py", line 522, in
_input_type_check
    raise TypeError(msg) from err TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not NoneType

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 692, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 936, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 931, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 923, in
_call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 2601, in read
    values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], record, use_name_get)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 4754, in
__getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 941, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 1052, in determine_value
    self.compute_value(recs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 1008, in compute_value
    self._compute_value(records)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 1001, in _compute_value
    self.compute(records)   File "<decorator-gen-131>", line 2, in _compute_expiry_date   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 369, in loop
    result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 369, in <listcomp>
    result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]   File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/addons/br_base/models/res_company.py", line 100, in
_compute_expiry_date
    except crypto.Error: NameError: name 'crypto' is not defined
```

Please, help!

Comment: Debug this file /opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/fields.py. Maybe there is a bug

Comment: I fixed uninstalling the module **br_base** on Apps.

Comment: I would first try to fix it by updating Odoo from the git. This might be an old issue and you might need br_base in the future...

Comment: You are missing `OpenSSL.crypto`